# Statistical independence of combining random samples

Tags: probability, sampling, independence, partitioning

Given a single finite population of size N, if I obtain S random samples from the data (replacing after each one), and randomly partition these into 2 sets of S/2 random samples, can I treat these two sample distributions as statistically independent?

If, somehow, I am able to identify duplicates, are the two sets statistically independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samples taken with replacement can be combined or split in whatever way, and the results can be treated as samples with replacement. Samples without replacement cannot be combined or split in meaningful ways: the splits will have insufficient variability, and mergers can have duplicates. You need to take a look at a sampling book like [Lohr (2009)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0495105279).

Answer (score 0):

The S random samples are, indeed, independent samples. They will still be independent if partitioned randomly into two groups. I am not sure what you mean by saying "can I treat these two sample distributions as statistically independent?" since you still have S random samples.  Are you talking about a statistic calculated from each sample?

Independence is preserved when you identify duplicates, assuming that your identification does not affect the sampling plan in any way.

Comment: I suspect that kitty implies $S$ observations drawn from the population of size $N$, rather than $S$ samples of whatever size. I.e., for her, "sample" means one case, one observation, one line of data.